# Access AWS EC2 REST API - Access issue

Tags: rest, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am trying to get details of EC2 Instances from AWS REST API using below

```
curl -X GET --header "Accept: application/json"  --header "AWSAccessKeyId:XXXXX" https://ec2.amazonaws.com/?Action=DescribeInstances&Signature=7fZH2gyinv9QoZdPz7ViR8JrBuqPDXjwg6jbCa8d
```

When I enter this, I get

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Response><Errors><Error><Code>MissingParameter</Code><Message>The request must contain the parameter AWSAccessKeyId</Message></Error></Errors><RequestID>e9d6281e-ace2-4010-ad60-6b01616e3eea</RequestID></Response>
```

is there something I am missing, I provided all access to the user in IAM

Comment: do you have a space between the ":" and the actual access key in your curl statement?

Comment: It looks like you are using your secret key as a signature and trying to send `AWSAccessKeyId` as a header.  Neither of these things is correct. http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/APIReference/Query-Requests.html#query-authentication

Answer (score 0):

Check the aws access key and secret key in `~/.aws/credentials` file.

run

`cat ~/.aws/credentials`

That may have some spell error.
Fix that with correct credentials, by editing that file.

or

run

`aws configure` and set new credentials.

I got the same error. Found a non printable character on the access key.
removing that solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

For what I can reply to your generic question is that is incorrect your approach.

You need to follow these links to get a correct GET for describing the instance.

First of all you can try to use some SDK or CLI if possible where the Authentication step are provided using Access_key and Secret_key of your account. The common place for aws under UNIX system is $HOME/.credentials

Else follow these guides:

- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/create-signed-request.html
- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/create-signed-request.html#add-signature-to-request

Your API is used in the latter link. Good luck and authenticate your API call.

Best regards